# Python - check if child classes overrides differ from parent class

Tags: python, oop

I've got a base class, from which around 10 top-level subclasses are inherited. Then from those 10 top-level subclasses ~400 child ones are inherited. Over years there accumulated some unneeded overrides, which just duplicate the code from parent class (e.g. a method was first overridden in `subclass a1`, then the same override was added to `subclass a` and wasn't removed from `subclass a1`)

The structure is like this, but much larger:

```
base
    - subclass a
        - subclass a1
        - subclass a2
        - subclass a3
    - subclass b
        - subclass b1
    - subclass c
        - subclass c1
        - subclass c2
```

What I'd like to do is programmatically detect whether implementations of methods are different between child and parent classes, so I can remove unneeded overrides. Is there any tool that can help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: How similar do you expect the duplicated code to be? Exactly copy and pasted lines? Do you want to detect if code has only very small, trivial changes, that don't modify its behavior?

Comment: Exact copy would be great at this point. If more complex duplicate detection is possible with some tool it would be even better

Comment: Hmm, I was playing around with comparing the `__code__` attribute of potentially duplicated functions, and for trivial examples it works, but it's pretty fragile. It doesn't work for subclasses defined in separate modules, for example. Probably you could compare some subset of the code object's attributes (excluding ones like `co_filename` that you'd expect to change some times) and make something work. Just comparing the bytecode (`co_code`) is not great as that can allow methods like `def foo(self): return 1` and `def foo(self): return 2` to match. But maybe it's good enough for your code?